# MATLAB - EEGLAB: surpress GUI for pop_eegfiltnew()

Tags: matlab, eeglab

I am working on some scripts for which I use several functions from the EEGLAB package for matlab. Most of these functions make it possible to surpress the GUI from showing, for example using `f( ... 'gui','off')`, or by using a different version of the same function. However, I can not figure out how to do this for the function `pop_eegfiltnew()`. Two similar functions are `eegfilt()`, which seems to be an outdated version of the function, and `firfilt()` however, `pop_eegfiltnew()` has more arguments than these other two, so they are certainly not the same in functional terms.

Anyone knows how to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you supply enough arguments to `pop_eegfiltnew` it does not pop up a GUI.
For example if you wanted to filter your signal 1 Hz highpass you would:

```
 EEG = pop_eegfiltnew(EEG, 1, 0);
```

This is because the first argument of `pop_eegfilt` is `EEG` structure, the second is `locutoff` (lower edge of the passband) and the third is `hicutoff` (higher edge of the passband).